# Stumped practicing Javascript making a D20 dice roller

Tags: javascript

So I'm relatively new to coding in general, but have only been learning Javascript for the past 2ish weeks. I decided I wanted to try practicing some of what I learned making a dice roller that rolls a 20 sided die and adds in a bonus from an Object loosely based on a D&D character.

Ive gotten some great help from friends who even helped build this code with me, but the expected results still arent coming out. I'm sure there could be something quite obvious I've left out or messed up, but I'm just not seeing it.

I've tried logging each function to see what it's spitting out, and each seems to "roll" a different number. My best guess is that the "atkRoll" function is the culprit, and isn't passing through the previous return as I expected. I'm also really unsure of my parameters and arguments and feel like those could be an issue as well.

I'd appreciate any help pointing me in the right direction, though I'm still new so be gentle!! Thanks!

```js
let myCharOne = {
  name: 'Zolda',
  class: 'Wizard',
  maxHp: 100,
  currentHp: 75,
  atkBonus: 7,
  magicBonus: 10
}

function diceRoll(min, max) {
  let minNum = min;
  let maxNum = max;
  let mathLogic = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  return mathLogic
}

function atkRoll(min, max) {
  let diceResult = diceRoll(min, max);
  diceResult + myCharOne.atkBonus;
  return diceResult;
}

function makeAtk(minimum, maximum) {
  let theRoll = diceRoll(minimum, maximum);
  let addingBonus = atkRoll();

  let printedStatement = `You rolled a ${theRoll} for a total of ${addingBonus}!`;
  return printedStatement;
}

console.log(makeAtk(1, 20))
```

Comment: What are the expected results and what are you getting instead?

Comment: `diceResult + myCharOne.atkBonus` should be `diceResult += myCharOne.atkBonus;`

Comment: Welcome!
You are calling `atkRoll()` with no arguments (minimum and maximum) in `function makeAtk`.

Comment: In your makeAtk function.```let addingBonus = atkRoll();``` You are missing the ```minimum, maximum``` it should be ```let addingBonus = atkRoll(minimum, maximum)```

Comment: Since the dice is 20 sided, consecutive values from 1 to 20, no need to pass arguments, just use: `Math.floor(20 * Math.random()) + 1`.

Comment: You are setting, but not using, `minNum` and `maxNum` in `function diceRoll(...)`.

Comment: In `function atkRoll`, you might want to add the player as an argument: `function atkRoll(player) { return player.atkBonus; }` - this way you can re-use the code for many players (if you need to add the dice roll, you can "roll" it in the function).

Comment: Great suggestions already, thanks!! The expected result would be the dice roll being adding to the atkBonus from the object and then those numbers being returned in the "printedStatement" string. So the first function for instance could roll a 10, it should pass it down into the next function where it's added to the atkBonus property, which are then both passed into the last function for the statement. Sorry if thats a mouthful!

Comment: If you pass the player as an argument, you can customize the "printedStatement".

Comment: I'd make an array of players.
This way, I can control the turns + have the stats handy.
Then you can call `someFunction(playerIndex)` and get the needed information from `players[playerIndex]`, `players[playerIndex].atkBonus` - for example.

Comment: Things to consider:
Do players go in-turn?
Is skipping a turn a thing?
Does reversing the direction of play happens?
Is the dice rolled every turn?
Are all turns attacks?
As you can tell, I've never played DND (wanted to, but didn't know how, and with whom)...

Comment: Here's an unrelated improvement. I would change `function diceRoll(min, max) {` to `function diceRoll(max, min = 0) {` so that you only need to send in the number of sides of the die: `diceRoll(6)` for 1d6. You can also remove minNum and maxNum from that method. I do love that you return a variable in each method. That makes the code much easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`diceResult + myCharOne.atkBonus` doesn't do anything useful; it adds the two numbers, but doesn't do anything with the result. If you want to add the bonus to `diceResult`, use `+=`.

In `makeAtk()` you're calling `atkRoll()` without any arguments. It needs the `min` and `max` arguments.

But if you call `diceRoll()` and then `atkRoll()` also calls it, they're going to get different rolls. If you need to know the original roll and the bonus, `atkRoll()` should take the original dice roll as an argument, not call `diceRoll()` again.

```js
let myCharOne = {
  name: 'Zolda',
  class: 'Wizard',
  maxHp: 100,
  currentHp: 75,
  atkBonus: 7,
  magicBonus: 10
}

function diceRoll(min, max) {
  let minNum = min;
  let maxNum = max;
  let mathLogic = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  return mathLogic
}

function atkRoll(diceResult) {
  return diceResult + myCharOne.atkBonus;
}

function makeAtk(minimum, maximum) {
  let theRoll = diceRoll(minimum, maximum);
  let addingBonus = atkRoll(theRoll);

  let printedStatement = `You rolled a ${theRoll} for a total of ${addingBonus}!`;
  return printedStatement;
}

console.log(makeAtk(1, 20))
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are receiving two different outputs for the dice roll because you call `diceRoll` twice within your code: `makeAtk` contains a `diceRoll` and `atkRoll` call, but `atkRoll` itself includes a `diceRoll` call:

```
function atkRoll(min, max) {
  //you call diceRoll here:
  let diceResult = diceRoll(min, max);
  ...
}
```

I would suggest passing the returned `diceRoll` into `atkRoll` as an argument like so:

```
function atkRoll(roll) {
  let rollPlusAddedBonus = roll + myCharOne.atkBonus;
  return rollPlusAddedBonus;
}

function makeAtk(minimum, maximum) {
  let theRoll = diceRoll(minimum, maximum);
  let addingBonus = atkRoll(theRoll);

  let printedStatement = `You rolled a ${theRoll} for a total of ${addingBonus}!`;
  return printedStatement;
}

console.log(makeAtk(1, 20))
```